# using eval-expression.net to evaluate items of a dictionary, as if they were properties of an object

Tags: c#, expression

I'm experimenting with [eval-expression.net](https://eval-expression.net/) and I want to evaluate expressions like "One.Id==1" instead of "customers["One"].Id==1" ('One' is actually a key in a Dictionary<string, Customer>)

pls see below an example: my idea was to use aliases to instruct the library to replace "One" with customers["One"], but this lead to an EvalException: "The type could not be found."

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to achieve the desired result?

```
[TestMethod()]
public void Register1()
{
    Dictionary<string, Customer> customers = new()
    {
        { "One", new Customer() { Id = 1 } },
        { "Two", new Customer() { Id = 2 } }
    };
    var evalContext = new EvalContext();
    var r1 = evalContext.Execute<bool>("customers[\"One\"].Id==1", new { customers }); 
    foreach (var i in customers)
    {
        evalContext.RegisterAlias(i.Key, $"customers[\"{i.Key}\"]");
    }
    var r2 = evalContext.Execute<bool>("One.Id==1", new { customers }); //EvalException
}

class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```